# mobile push extract problem

Tags: data, mobile, push, cloud

Currently we are trying to obtain the detailed mobile push data from the last 24 hours daily but the Mobile Push Detail Extract report only provides: **Rolling range** from 1 day which captures 12AM to 12 AM of the day before and **Specific range** which is set manually.
There is a third option that let you call the las 24 hours but the data is too much it doesn't work.

Is there any aproach we are not seeing?